# Swift/SpriteKit - Collisions and Objects

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, collision-detection, skphysicsbody, skphysicscontact

I have a class called Item, and inside there is an instance variable called itemNode which is of type SKSpriteNode. In my GameScene class, when I create an instance of Item I create a physics body that is given to the Item's itemNode. In my collision detection system, when my character's physics body collides with the itemNode's physics body, I want to preform a function on the Item object whose node's physics body just collided. However, the collision system only returns to physics body. How do I access the Item object given only the physics body of the node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SKPhyicsBody class has a [node property](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsBody/node) which points to the SKNode instance it is attached to.

Your collision detection code can look something like this:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    var item: SKSpriteNode
    var character: SKSpriteNode

    //Change this on the basis of the order of your categoryBitMask values
    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask)
    {
        item = contact.bodyA.node as SKSpriteNode
        character = contact.bodyB.node as SKSpriteNode
    }
    else
    {
        item = contact.bodyB.node as SKSpriteNode
        character = contact.bodyA.node as SKSpriteNode
    }

    //Perform necessary operations on item and character
}
```

**EDIT:**
In order to get access to the Item instance that declares the node, you will have to store a variable within the node which points to the Item instance. For this, you can either subclass SKSpriteNode and include a property, or use the [userData](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKNode/userData)
property of SKNode

Subclassing:

```
//New Class
class ItemNode: SKSpriteNode {

    static var itemInstance
}

//In the Item class declare the itemNode using this class
let itemNode = ItemNode()
itemNode.itemInstance = self
```

UserData property:

```
item.userData = NSMutableDictionary(object: self, forKey: "ItemInstance"))
```

Comment: Thanks, this gets me one step closer. But now that I have the node (which is an instance variable of the Item class), is there a way to access the Item object that the node is a part of?